# getenv core dump error in daemon service program

Tags: c++, daemon

I wrote a daemon service program and I want to open a file in /home/user path while the service is active. But I don't want to open file as root. The first thing I tried for this was to get the user name with the getenv("USER") function, keep it in a string, and then open a txt file with this string path. But after daemonize the program getenv function caused core dump.

```
int main(){
    make_daemon();

    const char *userName = "USER";
    const char *homePath = "/home/";
    const char *env_p = getenv(userName);   //Core dump!

    std::string m_filePath = homePath;
    m_filePath += env_p;
    m_filePath += "/test.txt"; // "/home/<user>/test.txt"

    //open filePath
    //some stuff...

}
```

I can probably solve this problem by running the service as root and creating a text file somewhere in the /usr/local/ path, but I want to create the text file with the user, not root. Is it possible or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: getenv and its derivatives always fail with daemon program. Since the processes that I do are linked to the text file, I need to create a text file somehow.

Comment: If you want to know the current user's home directory, then `getuid() -> getpwuid() -> pw_dir` ?

Comment: So some user starts this daemon process, it runs as root, and it opens a file called `tests.txt` **in a directory specified by the user**.  **If** you get it working, what's going to happen if the user does something like `ln -s /etc/shadow /home/$USER/test.txt` and then starts this process?

Comment: Are you sure that something exports `USER` environment variable? Normally the variable is unset. Only _in shell_ the variable is set _by bash_, I don't think it's generally set. `I wrote a daemon service` How do you run the service? Do you set `USER` environmetn variable when running?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @KamilCuk I also tried other environmental variables, but the getenv() function does not work due to the program flow. I think it gives an error because the program runs as daemon before getenv() function.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think I can do the situation you mentioned with the system() function. But the problem is, how do I specify the path to the file I linked to in the open() function? I mean, in the open() function I need to specify the file path to be able to open the file. For example, I need to specify the file path like "/home/some_user/test.txt". How can I do this with a symbolic link?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Is the example not minimal and clear enough for you? Can you help me understand which part you are criticizing?

Comment: It is not reproducible. I cannot copy, paste and compile it as is. If I replace `make_daemon` with `daemon` and add necessary header files, the program works as expected (i.e. does nothing and finishes normally).

Comment: `oes not work due to the program flow` What do you mean "does not work"? Maybe _the variables are not set_? You do not check for `NULL`.